# Dockerized MSSQL Server refuses connection from debugger

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am running docker on my windows pc (linux containers).
I have an MSSQL container.
Connection with Management Studio is working flawlessly.

I am using the exact same credentials for login through the entity framework.

Login is done through DbContext.

```
public ProductionContext()
    : base(Settings.Default.Entities)
{

}
```

My conn string looks like this:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1:1433;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pa55w0rd!
```

I am sure the user id and password works, and that the AdventureWorks database exists.

Do I need to enable some kind of external connection on my container?

Not sure what I am doing wrong, thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what "refuses connection from debugger" further? What are you doing and what exact message do you get?

Comment: Not :1433 but (comma)1433. `Data Source=localhost,1433;....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so Max in comments posted the solution to this.

Thanks!!

The correct conn string as follows:

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pa55w0rd!
```

Also there is a small workaround to the IP address in your connection string as I learned today:
You can use `host.docker.internal` which automatically resolves the docker IP.